# Cloning Machine with VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox, clone

I am trying to clone a VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.10 instance for a remote machine. I am using VirtualBox Version 5.1.22 r115126 (Qt5.6.2).

I have used Machine...Clone to clone the hard disk, which is a .vdi in a folder, which I copy to the remote. When I create the new machine on the remote I choose to use existing hard disk, which I point to the .vdi.

I check settings, and the Controller is the optical drive .iso as desired, and the SATA controller is pointing to my .vdi.

When starting the new instance on the remote, it goes through the usual Ubuntu setup, creating a partition, config, etc. as if I were creating a new instance. There is nothing about the new instance that resembles my old one, it is new. In settings, the SATA controller is still my .vdi (the cloned one).

Can't I just create the instance, fire it up, and resume as if it's my old machine? If not, how many steps, and what are they?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you booting the Virtual Machine HDD, or the Ubuntu ISO (that is also attached)?  From your description, it sounds like you are booting off the Ubuntu ISO rather than the HDD. Tried removing the ISO and just leave it with just the HDD attached and see what happened?

Comment: That works. I was under misconception about the controller. Thanks!